# Take screenshot using watir extension element screenshot

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir web driver, to go to url and fetch screenshot.

I am able to take screenshot for whole page, unable to take particular element. I tried watir extension element still not able to figure it.

This is my code

```
require "watir"
require 'watir/extensions/element/screenshot'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://images.morefrom.co.uk/prodmainimg.aspx?pn=7350022730991&man=Multibrackets"
browser.screenshot.save 's.jpg'
```

I want to take screenshot of particular image in page there is no div, i tried

```
browser.body.img.screenshot.save 's.jpg'
```

`screenshot': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

What should i be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found it

```
browser.body.img.screenshot("s.jpg")
```